# R core dump or crash session or abort when doing mutate_each scale

Tags: r, dplyr

I am a bit frustrated here... So I have a dataset that I need to scale the variables.  I have more than 44 variables, but realized the number of operations on all of the variables was probably consuming too much memory (not likely given I have 8 Gb RAM, but I don't know).

When I do the following MWE code, my R crashes, or aborts, or causes a core dump.

```
library(dplyr)
matrix(runif(44*500), ncol = 44) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(scale(.))))
```

About 70% of the time this causes a crash. Why is it happening and why is it not always happening?

I tried with even less variables (from 44 to 22) and it still has some problems (MWE below).

```
matrix(runif(22*500), ncol = 22) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(scale(.))))
```

Can anyone give some insight into why this is happening? Should I **not** scale the variables in this way? Is there a better way?

Comment: See https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1228

Comment: I put these MWE up with that issue, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is not left open and for those coming to see the question. This problem has been fixed in later versions of `dplyr` since this question was asked.

Running the code above no longer has any issue.